# Is it possible to create a folder under Windows Explorer "Libraries" ussing Inno setup installer?

Tags: inno-setup, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I am using Inno installer and I would like to create a custom library  that will appear as a folder under the Windows "Libraries" folder in Windows Explorer.

Can I do this using Inno installer and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can. For instance by using [`SHAddFolderPathToLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378432(v=vs.85).aspx). The problem is that proper translation of all the shell interfaces needed for about two function calls is quite long. You might try to fake that proper translation and re-type some parameters, so it might be easier, but that's not what I would like to do. Or, maybe there's an easier way that I overlooked...